# how switching from italian to german from internal to internal URL

Tags: php

Now when I’m on an internal page of the italian version if I select “deutsch” I land to the home page in german. Is it possible landing to the same internal page in german? my website:[test.sacconicase.com](https://test.sacconicase.com/)
In wp-config.php I have

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

all German internal page slugs are the same as Italian page slugs.
I wonder if I have to change this code in functions.php:

```
add_filter('locale', 'lang_by_subdomain');
function lang_by_subdomain( $lang ) {

if (0 === strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'de.')) {
  // set to German
  return 'de_DE';


} else {
  // return original language
  return $lang;


}
```

}